# Unable to add values in a loop to associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I wan't to add values continuously in a while loop in associative array. I have used the following technique, but when I am displaying it, it stores the last value only and by searching I have found out that people do the same. What is the problem in the code?

My Php code is:

```
while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
            {
           $first=$row2['MDid'];
           $second=$row2['MD_FullName'];          

           $data=array($first=>$second);

            }

           var_dump($data);
```

My Output is:

`array(75) { [0]=> array(1) { ["AB0001"]=> string(29) "Arthur Boshnack, M.D, F.A.C.G" } [1]=> array(1) { ["AJ0001"]=> string(16) "Anwer Jaffri, MD" } [2]=> array(1) { ["AK0001"]=> string(16) "Dr.Adam Kotowski" } [3]=> array(1) { ["ALZ001"]=> string(22) "Kheir Al-Zouhayli, M.D" } [4]=> array(1) { ["AM0001"]=> string(17) "Dr.Ambrose Mgbako" } [5]=> array(1) { ["AMW001"]=> string(21) "Dr.Audrey M. Weissman" } [6]=> array(1) { ["AN0001"]=> string(25) "Dr.Anthony Napolitano,M.D" } [7]=> array(1) { ["BS0001"]=> string(17) "Bhupendra Shah,MD" } [8]=> array(1) { ["BT0001"]=> string(19) "Dr.Birendra Trivedi" } [9]=> array(1) { ["CA0001"]=> string(14) "Claudia Aroche" } [10]=> array(1) { ["CG0001"]=> string(13) "Dr.Cary Golub" } [11]=> array(1)`

But when I echo:

```
$data["VSV001"]
```

I get nothing

Comment: `$data[$first]= $second;`..

Comment: Or `$data[] = array($first=>$second);` (depending on exactly what you want to do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing it like this.

```
while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
    $first=$row2['MDid'];
    $second=$row2['MD_FullName'];          
    $data[$first]= $second;
}
var_dump($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
       $data=array();
       while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
        {
       $first=$row2['MDid'];
       $second=$row2['MD_FullName'];          

       $data[]=array($first=>$second);

        }

       var_dump($data);
```

Do not use just

```
$data["VSV001"]
```

You have to use like

```
$data[73]["VSV001"]
```

Instead of 73 use your index number.

```
 { [0]=> array(1) { ["AB0001"]=> string(29) "Arthur Boshnack, M.D, F.A.C.G" }
```

like

```
echo $data[0]["AB0001"];
```

You will get output like

```
Arthur Boshnack, M.D, F.A.C.G
```

Comment: This is not wrong...but is wrong according to the requirement.
This way it will insert the new array at a new index in `$data` array, which is wrong

Comment: Instead of `var_dump($data)` use `print_r($data)` it looks better

Answer (score 0):

I wan't to add values continuously in a while loop in associative array. I have used the following technique, but when I am displaying it, it stores the last value only and by searching I have found out that people do the same. What is the problem in the code?

```
       $data=array(); //declare it globally, some versions of php need initialization of the variables when they are accessed out of any scope.

       while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
       {
        $first=$row2['MDid'];
        $second=$row2['MD_FullName'];          
        $data[$first]=>$second;
       }

       var_dump($data);
```